# Mongodb Schema issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here i am using Nodejs application to get JSON response from external API.I need to capture few key-value pair of this response and need to save it MongoDB.
I am getting the response properly, but i am unable to save the data in database.

**Requirement:**

Each time i get this response from External server , i need to save it in table by rewriting any documents if already exists in this collection. Here i have nearly 7 array items in json response , i need to save corresponding key value pair from all of the items automatically .

Model:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const getAllUsersDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        userRefID:[] ,
        userName:[],
        divisionId: [{}],
        divisionName:[{}],
        emailId :[{}],
    })
    module.exports = getAllUsers = mongoose.model('getAllUsers',getAllUsersDataSchema );

**API Call where i am capturing external  API response:**

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const config = require('../config');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const getAllUsers = require ('../db/getAllUsersListmodel');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect ('mongodb://localhost/testdb',{ useUnifiedTopology: true , useNewUrlParser: true });

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // token in session -> get user data and send it back to the Angular app
   
    var data =fs.readFileSync('../teamlist.txt',  {encoding:'utf8'} )
    console.log(data);

    if (data) {
      request(
        {
          method: 'GET',
         
          url: 'https://api.mypurecloud.com/api/v2/users',

          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data
          }
        },
  
        // callback
        (error, response, body) => {

          let userInfoResponse = JSON.parse(body);
          res.send(userInfoResponse);
          console.log(userInfoResponse.entities.length)
          console.log(userInfoResponse.entities[0].division.id)

          getAllUsers.create({
            userRefID : userInfoResponse.entities.id,
            userName: userInfoResponse.entities.name,
            divisionId: userInfoResponse.entities.division.id,
            divisionName:userInfoResponse.entities.division.name,
           emailId:userInfoResponse.entities.primaryContactInfo.address      
        }, (error,post)=>{
            console.log(error,post);
        });
}
          );
        }

// no token -> send nothing
    else {
      res.send("Token Not Present - Kindly login in back");
    }

    //console.log(req.session.token);
       
  });
```

Data is saving in DB but not getting any array data saved in to it.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fd998d61439a434983702cd"),
        "userRefID" : [ ],
        "userName" : [ ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

This is exact API JSON response i am trying to save it in DB and use it for future references:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
      "name": "EPS Purecloud Support",
      "division": {
        "id": "36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f",
        "name": "",
        "selfUri": "/api/v2/authorization/divisions/36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f"
      },
      "chat": {
        "jabberId": "5dcc25e1db8c7e19238a287d@cognizant3.orgspan.com"
      },
      "email": "eps@genesys.com",
      "primaryContactInfo": [
        {
          "address": "eps@genesys.com",
          "mediaType": "EMAIL",
          "type": "PRIMARY"
        }
      ],
      "addresses": [],
      "state": "active",
      "username": "eps@genesys.com",
      "version": 3,
      "acdAutoAnswer": false,
      "selfUri": "/api/v2/users/07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61"
    },
    {
      "id": "c5ce06dc-6265-4d16-be18-f5fc5a918295",
      "name": "Generic",
      "division": {
        "id": "36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f",
        "name": "",
        "selfUri": "/api/v2/authorization/divisions/36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f"
      },
      "chat": {
        "jabberId": "5ebab3dba6686314f6913b98@cognizant3.orgspan.com"
      },
      "email": "integration-generic-a03293c0-945d-11ea-a64c-ebeb45b9d295@webhook.com",
      "primaryContactInfo": [
        {
          "address": "integration-generic-a03293c0-945d-11ea-a64c-ebeb45b9d295@webhook.com",
          "mediaType": "EMAIL",
          "type": "PRIMARY"
        }
      ],
      "addresses": [],
      "state": "active",
      "username": "integration-generic-a03293c0-945d-11ea-a64c-ebeb45b9d295@webhook.com",
      "version": 2,
      "acdAutoAnswer": false,
      "selfUri": "/api/v2/users/c5ce06dc-6265-4d16-be18-f5fc5a918295"
    },
  {
   /**  3rd User *********/
  }
{
   /**  4th User *********/
  }

],
  "pageSize": 25,
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "total": 7,
  "firstUri": "/api/v2/users?pageSize=25&pageNumber=1",
  "selfUri": "/api/v2/users?pageSize=25&pageNumber=1",
  "lastUri": "/api/v2/users?pageSize=25&pageNumber=1",
  "pageCount": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities is an array of objects, but you are trying to refer to its properties as an object:

```
userRefID : userInfoResponse.entities.id, // but "entities": [ {"id":"...", "name":"..."} ],
userName: userInfoResponse.entities.name,
```

You have to collect the data in a loop, and only then insert it into the database:

```
const usersArray = userInfoResponse.entities.map(el => ({
  userRefID : el.id,
  userName: el.name,
  divisionId: el.division.id,
  divisionName: el.division.name,
  emailId: el.primaryContactInfo[0].address
}));

getAllUsers.insertMany(usersArray)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  Yuri. I have few more concerns related with this.
a.Whenever i got the response, i need to rewrite the old data inside collection already present with this new data.
b.whether i have option put this data under array inside the database.Like this,
userData:[
{
"userRefID":"337984b2-cf2f-49c8-84e9-3c2bc7b1f197",
"userName" :"TestUser",
"divisionId" :"36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f",
"emailId" :"testuser@cognizant.com"
 },
{
 2nd data
}
]

Comment: @hari If you need to overwrite the data, first delete all the old data: await getAllUsers
      .deleteMany();

Comment: @hari about 2nd question: use .update() with $push: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/